# Filtering elements out of a html list using javascript

Tags: javascript, list

So I have a list of items and a text box, and I want to apply the hidden attribute to the items not matching what is in the text box.  I am using javascript to do this on the browser in real time.  Here is my HTML (don't worry abou the g:textbox, i'm doing this in grails)

```
Filter List :<g:textBox id = filter onkeyup = Javascript:filter()>

<ul id = 'terms'>
    <li id = 'AFUE'>AFUE
        <p> Annualized Fuel Utilization Efficiency is a measure of your furnace’s heating efficiency. The higher the AFUE percentage, the more efficient the furnace. The minimum percentage established by the DOE for furnaces is 78.</p>
    </li>
    <li id = 'Airflow'>Airflow
        <p> The distribution or movement of air. </p>
    </li>
    <li id = 'Air Handler/Coil Blower'>Air Handler/Coil Blower
        <p> The indoor part of an air conditioner or heat pump that moves cooled or heated air throughout the ductwork of your home. An air handler is usually a furnace or a blower coil.</p>
    </li>
    <li id = 'Bioaerosols'>Bioaerosols
        <p>Microscopic living organisms that grow and multiply in warm, humid places.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So i have the html setup, now I need to write the javascript.
 1. I'm not sure if i'm using the filter.text correctly and 
 2. not sure how to get to the li ids inside the ul id

```
function filter(){
   // on each li item in ul where ul id = 'terms'
   {
      if //li item id.match(${filter.text})
      {
           //li item.hidden = "false"
      }
      else if !//li item id.match(${filter.text})
      {
           //li item.hidden = "true"
      }
      else if ${filter.text} = ""
      {
           //set all items hidden = "false"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to say I need to iterate over a collection of elements, but that just may be the ruby/cucumber coming out of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filterText = document.getElementById('filter').value,
    lis = document.querySelectorAll('#terms li'),
    x;

for (x = 0; x < lis.length; x++) {
    if (filterText === '' || lis[x].innerHTML.indexOf(filterText) > -1) {
        lis[x].removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
    else {
        lis[x].setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bWRkz/

Comment: this does not work completely as expceted.  This searches the text of the list item, want it to search the ID

Comment: @MattWestlake oh, I apologize.  Simply change `innerHTML` to `id` above: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bWRkz/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to search the `<li>` id values in plain javascript:

```
function keyTyped(e) {
    var items = document.getElementById("terms").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var matches = [];
    var typed = e.target.value;
    var text, i;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        text = items[i].id;
        if (!typed || text.indexOf(typed) != -1) {
            matches.push(items[i]);
        }
    }
    // now hide all li tags and show all matches
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // now show all matches
    for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        matches[i].style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wFEJ5/

This demo actually hides the elements so you can see them visually in the demo.  You can obviously change the code to add/remove the hidden attribute if that's the end result you eventually want.

Comment: Also searches the text, i want it to search the ID

Comment: @MattWestlake - maybe you should clarify your question then.  That was not clear to me at all.  You got two answers that both searched the text.

Comment: @MattWestlake - answer modified to search the `<li>` id only.